# Django form is_valid() fails and add_error() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, django, post

I am creating news site with stripe subscription. The following code is failing at the is_valid() check. But I do not understand why: The form should get its data filled from the POST-data or not?

Model:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

ModelForm:

```
class CustomUserForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("full_name", "email", "stripe_id")

    def add_error(self, message):
        # pylint: disable=E1101
        self._errors[NON_FIELD_ERRORS] = self.error_class([message])
```

View function:

```
def charge(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                    amount=10000,
                    currency='usd',
                    description=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                    source=request.POST['stripeToken'],
                    card=form.cleaned_data['stripe_id'], 
                )

                form.save()
                return redirect('home')

            except stripe.error.CardError:
                form.add_error("The card has been declined.")
        else:
            print("Form is not valid")
    else:
        form = CustomUserForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form
    args['publishable'] = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    args['months'] = range(1, 13)
    args['years'] = range(2013, 2038)
    args['soon'] = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)

    return render(request, 'accounts/charge.html', args)
```

I found similar topics and tried a lot. However I am still stuck.
When I run this, it returns `add_error() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` and it highlights this `form.is_valid()` line.
I also tried to run it without `add_error`, then I found that form is invalid.
I am using python3.7 and Django 2.2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding an existing `add_error` method on the form class - you can see the source code here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L307

The internals of `is_valid` calls `self.add_error` with a field and error message, so when you override `add_error` to only take an error message then the invocation in `is_valid` is broken.

I would recommend renaming your custom `add_error` method to something else that doesn't conflict with the `Form` class, or use `add_error` in the same way as it is used internally, passing `None` for the field if you want the error to be a NON_FIELD_ERROR like so:

```
# change your view code to this after deleting your `add_error` method for the same result
form.add_error(None, "The card has been declined.")
```

Comment: I renamed my custom add_error and it became not to show error of add_error. Thank you very much. I cannot still run "if form.is_valid():" line, instead it goes to else line. Is it because I am wrong to input form ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, is_valid returns False if request.POST doesn't have valid values for the fields you've specified in the form

Comment: I could  finally make it. Appreciated !